# Should I return collection from factory to controller via function?

Tags: angularjs

I'm struggling with choosing the correct way of accessing collection located inside service from controller. I see two options, both have ups and downs:

**Returning function from service that returns collection:**

Service:

```
app.factory('healthService', function () {            
    var healths = [{},{},{},{}];

    function updateHealths() {
      healths = [...];
    }

    return {
        getHealths : function() {
          return healths;
        },

        update : function () {
          updateHealths();
        }};                          
});
```

Controller:

```
    $scope.healths = healthService.getHealths;
    $scope.update = healthService.update;
```

View:

```
    ng-repeat = "health in healths()"        
    ng-click = "update()"              '
```

I'm not sure about efficiency here- how often will healths() be evaluated?

**Giving the possibility to access collection directly from controller:**

Service:

```
app.factory('healthService', function () {            

    return {
        healths : [{},{},{},{}],
        update :function() {
           this.healths = [...];
        }                         
});
```

Controller:

```
   $scope.healthService = healthService;
```

View:

```
    ng-repeat = "health in healthService.healths"              '
    ng-click = "healthService.update()"
```

Which one is better, faster? Any other tips?

Comment: functions within markup are not efficient since angular digest cycles may call them many times

Comment: yes, I heard so, but should controller have the possibility to change service's attributes?

Comment: you missed option :  `$scope.healths = healthService.getHealths();` which removes function from markup

Comment: how often is .getHealths() triggered? is it efficient?

Comment: would only get called when controller initializes ( or if you call it again within controller). Digest cycles will only see the object that was returned and won't need to make function calls from markup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not try wrapping your collection in an object (which acts as a service state) to allow binding to occur on the object, rather than by exposing functions. For example:

```
app.factory('healthService', function() {

    var state = {
        healths: [...]
    };

    return {
        getState: function() { return state; },
        updateHealths: function() { state.healths = [...]; }
    };
});
```

Then inside your controller:

```
$scope.healthState = healthService.getState();
```

Then to reference your healths from your html, use:

```
<div ng-repeat="health in healthState.healths"></div>
```

Comment: Okay, thanks, but why do I need to wrap healths collection in state object? It works without it(returning healths, no wrappers). And what about efficiency, how often is getState() triggered? What if it would do some time consuming operations?

Comment: Firstly, you only run `getState()` once on controller init. This will setup the binding to the controller scope. The reason why you wrap the list in a parent object is so that if you change the list itself, any controller bound to the state wrapper will still be able to see the list after changing.

Comment: I'm not going to change the list that way, but it's good to know it, thanks a lot!